# Defining appropriate test function spaces for the finite element solution of Euler's fluid equations

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I have the following coupled equations for the conservation of mass and momentum of a compressible fluid

\begin{equation}
\rho_t + (\rho u)_z = 0,
\end{equation}

$$
(\rho u)_t + (\rho u^2)_z + \tfrac{1}{k}\rho_z = \left(\frac{dp}{dz}\right)_f + \rho g
$$
over the domain $[0, 2L]\times[0, \infty)$ for density and velocity $\rho = \rho(z, t)$, $u = u(z, t)$ respectively. Note that 
$$
g = g(z) = \begin{cases}
9.81 & \text{if } 0 \le z \le L
\\
-9.81 & \text{if } L < z \le 2L
\end{cases}
$$
and that $\left(\frac{dp}{dz}\right)_f$ is a frictional pressure term that is non-linear in $\rho$ and $u$.

The weak variational problem is: $\textit{find $u\in V_1, \rho\in V_2$ such that}$
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2L} v\rho_t - v_z\rho u dz = 0
\end{equation}
$$
\int_0^{2L}q(\rho u)_t - q_z\rho u^2 - \tfrac{1}{k}q_z\rho - q\left(\frac{dp}{dz}\right)_f - q\rho gdz = 0
$$
$\textit{for all test functions $v, q$ in spaces $V_1$, $V_2$ respectively.}$

I am then discretising these equations in time using an implicit backward Euler discretisation for implementation in the finite element solver software Firedrake (this is a standard approach when using Firedrake).

The problem I'm having is that the Firedrake solver does not converge with the inclusion of $\left(\frac{dp}{dz}\right)_f$, and gives the wrong solution when $\left(\frac{dp}{dz}\right)_f$ is excluded.

So in order to narrow down the causes of this divergence, my question is: are there specific spaces for $V_1$ and $V_2$ that should be used for this kind of variational problem?